# Filtering data from json response object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an API call that returns a JSON response object. The shape of the data is bit a confusing and I can't figure out the exact object to run `.map()` and `.filter()` on to get my desired result.

```
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response); //see below for shape of data
    var dataSourceInfo = response.data.included.filter(
      element => element.type === "DataSource"
    );
    var dataSourceName = dataSourceInfo.map(function(included) {
      return included["name"];
    });
    console.log(dataSourceName);
```

In the two arrays, I'm attempting to filter over `response.data.included` to find an element by type. Then map over the returned filter to create a new ordered array. In one of the `included` arrays there is an identifying `type` of `DataSource`, here's an example:

```
included: [
  {
    id: "2147483604",
    type: "DataSource",
    name: "Some DataSource"
  },
```

I'm logging the `dataSourceName` but the array only has the one of the expected names, and it's only from the first array, so it's like the map isn't reaching the second `data.data`. Any idea how I can get both names to appear in the filtered array?

Edit: correct response object is in the codesandbox

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding your problem

Comment: I can see that `response` is an array so `response.data` should throw an error. It should be `response[0].data` or `response.forEach/map/filter()`

Comment: What is the expected result ?

Comment: So there's a `type` element of `DataSource` in one of the `included` arrays in `response[0]` and `response[1]` so the filter map should return `[ dataSourceName1, dataSourceName2]`

Comment: There must be a mistake in the textual representation you added for the response object. You depict it as an array of ***one*** element (not two), and that element is an object in which you define the `data` property twice, so only one will survive (an object cannot have two properties with the same name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want a flat list of `name`s where `type` is `"DataSource"` given an input that looks like this:

```js
const response = {
  data: [
    {
      data: {
        data: {
          included: [
            { type: 'DataSource', name: 'First' },
            { type: 'Blah', name: 'Second' },
            { type: 'DataSource', name: 'Third' }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      data: {
        data: {
          included: [
            { type: 'DataSource', name: 'Fourth' },
            { type: 'Blah', name: 'Fifth' },
            { type: 'DataSource', name: 'Sixth' }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
  ]
}

const result = response.data.flatMap(({data: {data: {included}}}) => 
  included.reduce((memo, {type, name}) => {
    if (type === 'DataSource') {
      memo.push(name)
    }
    return memo;
  }, [])
)

console.log(result)
```

I've omitted parts of the response that aren't relative to the problem

**Update:**

Here's the code adjusted to work with the `responseObject` listed in https://codesandbox.io/s/ympo7pr0xx

```js
const responseObject = [ { data: { data: { id: "2147483605", selfUri: "/schedules/2147483605", type: "Schedule", startTime: 1545409610826, status: "InProgress", query: { id: "2147483603", selfUri: "/queries/2147483603", type: "Query" }, dataSource: { id: "2147483604", selfUri: "/datasources/2147483604", type: "DataSource" } }, included: [ { id: "2147483603", selfUri: "/queries/2147483603", type: "Query", name: "Query1", status: "Scheduled", querySchema: { id: "2147483601", selfUri: "/queryschemas/2147483601", type: "QuerySchema" } }, { id: "2147483601", selfUri: "/dataschemas/2147483601", type: "DataSchema", name: "Phone Data" }, { id: "2147483601", selfUri: "/queryschemas/2147483601", type: "QuerySchema", name: "QS1", dataSchema: { id: "2147483601", selfUri: "/dataschemas/2147483601", type: "DataSchema" }, queriesUri: "/queryschemas/2147483601/queries" }, { id: "2147483604", selfUri: "/datasources/2147483604", type: "DataSource", name: "Standalone- 5K", description: "Standalone 5K record" } ] } }, { data: { data: { id: "2147483606", selfUri: "/schedules/2147483606", type: "Schedule", startTime: 1545410049652, status: "Pending", query: { id: "2147483603", selfUri: "/queries/2147483603", type: "Query" }, dataSource: { id: "2147483608", selfUri: "/datasources/2147483608", type: "DataSource" } }, included: [ { id: "2147483608", selfUri: "/datasources/2147483608", type: "DataSource", name: "Standalone 5", description: "Standalone 5 record" }, { id: "2147483603", selfUri: "/queries/2147483603", type: "Query", name: "Query1", status: "Scheduled", querySchema: { id: "2147483601", selfUri: "/queryschemas/2147483601", type: "QuerySchema" }, schedulesUri: "/queries/2147483603/schedules" }, { id: "2147483601", selfUri: "/dataschemas/2147483601", type: "DataSchema", name: "Phone Data" }, { id: "2147483601", selfUri: "/queryschemas/2147483601", type: "QuerySchema", name: "QS1", dataSchema: { id: "2147483601", selfUri: "/dataschemas/2147483601", type: "DataSchema" } } ] } } ];

const result = responseObject.flatMap(({data: {included}}) => 
  included.reduce((memo, {type, name}) => {
    if (type === 'DataSource') {
      memo.push(name)
    }
    return memo;
  }, [])
)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I've updated my initial post, maybe this will give you a more clear understanding. I left out the irrelevant `included` arrays. So using map and filter I should be getting back `[Standalone 5K, Records 5K`]. It is currently only returning the first name `[Standalone 5K]`

Comment: ok, it looks like the only difference was an extra nested `data` - updated

Comment: actually, I rolled back the changes - doesn't my code do what you want?

Comment: I think I'm miscommunicating my problem, in the form of my data. Here's a link to my codesandbox reproducing my issue. https://codesandbox.io/s/ympo7pr0xx

Comment: the example `responseObject` you posted doesn't look right, it has this shape: `[{ data: { ... }, data: { ... } }]`, i.e. there's an object with two `data` keys - the second `data` will overwrite the first

Comment: I'm having trouble myself replicating the response object seen in the snapshot in the post and what's in the codesandbox.

Comment: try `console.log(JSON.stringify(response))`

Comment: or better yet, `console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2))`

Comment: This is logging the http response headers and such

Comment: my bad... `console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 2))`

Comment: that's probably the issue with mocked response in my code - it should be `response = {data: [ ... ]}` - I'll update

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(responseObject[0].data.data, null, 2))` this will print out - ```{
  "id": "2147483617",
  "selfUri": "/schedules/2147483617",
  "type": "Schedule",
  "status": "Complete"
} ```. Bouncing between the sandbox with mocked data and the actual response object from the server is mixing me up

Comment: @DJ2 The shape of `responseObject` given in the post is incorrect. Read the previous comments

Comment: taking another look at the screenshot, there is a nested `data`. also, if `response` includes the headers then the screenshot isn't `console.log(response)`

Comment: I have updated that same sandbox with the correct shape of data for `responseObject`

Comment: I'm adding `dataSourceNames` to my schedule object, but can't seem to get the names to render correctly in the table, any ideas?

Comment: It's the same link. It's fully up to date. I'm trying to render the names with `<td> {schedule.dataSourceNames} </td>`

Comment: Well I added `dataSourceNames` to the `schedule` object, so those array values should be accessible from `{schedules.dataSourceNames}`, unless I have to map over the array with the string values in it and pull them out again?

Comment: log out your `response in `getUpdatedStatus`

Comment: The `dataSourceNames` are printing to console when logged, but they seem to not be added to the schedule object correctly

Comment: So I think I narrowed down the problem: in `getUpdatedStatus` inside the `else if` block where I'm mapping over `schedules`, for each previous schedule, I'm returning a new schedule, but all new schedule have the same `dataSourceNames`.